# Éviter d’avoir à aller ou éviter d’aller ?

Tags: grammaire, infinitif

Je voudrais bien savoir quelle phrase est correcte ?

- *Je colle quand même le contenu pour éviter d’avoir à aller sur le lien.*
- *Je colle quand même le contenu pour vous évitez d’avoir à aller sur le lien.*
- *Je colle quand même le contenu pour éviter d’aller sur le lien.*
- *Je colle quand même le contenu pour vous évitez d’aller sur le lien.*

Answer (score 4):

La deuxième, en corrigeant l'infinitif :

> Je colle quand même le contenu pour vous éviter d’avoir à aller sur le lien.

« Pour éviter d'avoir » voudrait dire que c'est l'auteur de la phrase qui évite, pas le lecteur.

« Pour vous éviter d'aller » n'indique pas que c'est l'obligation que l'on souhaite éviter.

Answer (score 2):

"Aller" est un verbe plutôt imprécis... On *clique* sur un lien, on *consulte* une page après avoir *cliqué* sur un lien.

En la circonstance, bien que mon propos excède la question, j'écrirai :
"Je colle cependant le contenu pour vous éviter d'avoir à consulter la page originale."

Comment: Et on clique sur un lien. :) Dans ce cas, je dirais : "pour vous éviter d'avoir à cliquer sur le lien".